# Assembly x86-64: memcpy a word?

Tags: c, assembly, memcpy

I know memcpy() does this, but I'm interested in how should this code segment be written in `__asm__("..")` in C?

```
size_t memcpy_one_word(const char *p) {
    size_t res;
    char *pRes = (char *)&res; // this is a type cast so it won't be in assembly
    // assembly starts --
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) { *(pRes++) = *(p++); }
    // assembly ends --
    return res;
}
```

On 64-bit machine, sizeof(size_t) is 8.

Comment: Why not use the compilers `-S` option to generate the assembly code?

Comment: Check `movl/mov` ?

Comment: @l'L'l I tried before

Comment: `mov rax,[rdi]` `ret` in normal assembly, don't know about inline-asm in C. But having inline-asm variant will be toxic, as the proper C variant will get optimized out in most of the cases, but the inline-asm C would be compiled as real call to subroutine, as the compiler doesn't understand the assembly part, and can't effectively optimize out the whole construct as useless qword copy.

Comment: And the "proper" C variant is IMO `return *((size_t*)p);`, not sure why you added the `for` loop, etc... I'm not sure how much this code is abusing C and aliasing/casting rules, but on x86_64 target it should work well. For example [gcc 7.3 output](https://godbolt.org/g/9SGsQq) - is as expected (my asm in previous comment). (but I'm not C expert, only assembly ... and believe me, the inline-asm variant is good only for educational purposes, you certainly don't want it in some project source)

Comment: "*how should this code segment be written in `__asm__("..")` in C?*" It shouldn't. You lose all help the compiler can give you by embedding assembly within your C code. Unless you have an absolute performance critical bit of code, that for some reason you believe you can optimize better than what the compiler does, then you ought to leave the code as C and let the compiler do it's job. You also risk your code being moved or eliminated or duplicated by the compiler under certain circumstances. See the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: If you are concerned about the aliasing rules, like Ped7g, `memcpy` *is* the way to go. The code `memcpy(&res, p, sizeof res)` results in a single instruction `movq (%rdi), %rax`, just like the cast. Hard to get this down to *less* that one instruction.

Comment: @Ped7g Totally agree, a simple cast does the trick. I don't know why GCC used a __builtin_memcpy() to do this..([link: libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/hash_bytes.cc)). it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Leedehai I guess due to portability on other platforms, the `memcpy` will probably work better in portable source. Then again I would expect it even on x86_64 to produce that single `mov` instruction, so I'm confused what you were trying to achieve and why. (actually Bo confirmed all of this, and he knows lot more about C and C++, than me, I'm kind of stuck in the asm world, so I can just confirm that the final result on x86_64 using the single `mov` instruction is optimal in pretty much every way) - except the C solution may get optimized out to no instruction at all, in certain cases.